# JSP get/post with Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm trying to create a registration form. In this form there are some fields(username,password etc) and also a dropdown listbox. My problem is with this listbox.I manage to retrieve succesfully from a server all the items that will be added in the listbox and i want know to put it in this form.

More specific i have a list called lista, which contains the items i want to add in the listbox.

JSP:

```
<c:url var="attinto" value="/reg" />
<form:form modelAttribute="attribute" method="POST" action="${attinto}">
<table>
    .
            .

    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="researchareas">Research area:</form:label></td>
        <td>    
          <select multiple="multiple">   
            <c:forEach items="${researchareas}" var="researcharea">     
              <option value="${researcharea}">  ${researcharea} </option>                   
            </c:forEach>
          </select>    
        </td> 
    </tr>
```

Controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/reg", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getform(Model model) {

        getAll(model);
        model.addAttribute("attribute", new Reg());

        return "reg";
    }
```

I have to mention at this point that the getAll(model) is a void method similar to the following:

```
      model.addAttribute("researchareas",lista);
```

Then i create a POST method to send this data.

Question:How can i add in the form the data from the list(into a listbox)?How i can take back the values that the user will select?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, use `form:select` like this:

```
<form:select path="researchareas" items="${researchareas}" multiple="true" />
```

Then Spring could automatically bind corresponding attribute in Registration object:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/registration", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String getRegistrationForm( //
    @ModelAttribute("registrationAttribute") Registration registration, //
    BindingResult result, Model model) {
  ...
  return ...
}
```

Assuming Registration class has the following:

```
public class Registration {
  String username;
  String password;
  List<String> researchareas;

  ... corresponding getters and setters here
}
```

Though I'd name attribute the same as class or else you'd have to specify explicit names in the method parameters annotations.

Comment: Hallo Eugene.My problem is that i want to add in a dropdown listbox the data which there are into the lista.I don't have a problem with the POST(i.e. to send the data)

Comment: So, what's the problem? The researchareas list will be populated automatically. I've updated my answer with additional details on rendering select tag.

Comment: I agree with this answer by @Eugene. It should be the solution you want.

Comment: I agree too but i'm taking this:"org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'researchareas' of bean class [org.client.model.registration.Registration] Bean property 'researchareas' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?" And my Registration class is as Eugene wrote it.

Comment: + in the error shows also this: <td><form:label path="researchareas">Research area:</form:label></td>
    <td>    
                               <form:select path="researchareas" items="${researchareas}" multiple="true" />
                       </td>                                              And moreover when i put method = RequestMethod.POST says"HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'GET' not supported"

Answer (score 2):

Please specify **post** method in your form in jsp and also in controller specify **method=RequestMethod.POST**.

One more thing.

There should not be the list as your data type for researchareas in your Registration class.
Try giving the datatype as **String[]**

Hope this works for you.
Cheers.